# prototypes are correct but garbage values are displayed in the output

Tags: c

The prototype (`void example();`) I have mentioned for the program is correct, but the compiler is giving garbage value instead of correct values in the output.
What codes should be added or removed?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void example()
{
  static int x = 10;
  x=x+10;
  printf("\n%d",&x);
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
  {
    example();
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your coding style and indentation (or your knowledge of StackOverflow formatting) needs work. Please take the [tour] and read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What values do you consider correct and what does your program return?

Comment: `printf("\n%d",&x);`  -->  `printf("\n%d",x);`

Answer (score 4):

You are using an adress of a variable where printf wants just the value:

```
printf("\n%d",&x);
```

->

```
printf("\n%d",x);
```

Your result might also be improved by using `"%d\n"` instead.

Comment: I think the OP expects the address to be constant since `x` is a static variable.

Comment: @ForceBru that wouldn't matter, printf isn't going to accept the address of x when looking for a lvalue for %d.